# Nginx reverse proxy ignores cache headers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, cache-control

I'm using nginx as a load balancer. here is the simplified version of my nginx config file.

```
upstream myUpstream {
   server server1.com;
   server server2.com;
}

server{
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://myUpstream;
    }
}
```

to leverage browser caching for my rest api calls I set my backend servers to set cache headers which expires in 1 hour.

when I send my requests directly to server1.com or server2.com everything works perfectly and cache response headers are fine.

[image]

but when I send my requests to my load balancer server I get two cache response headers one from load balancer and another one from my backend server and browser dont cache my response.

[image]

my problem is how to configure my load balancer server so it wont put its own cache headers to my rest api responses?

here is my full nginx config file:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:100m rate=10r/s;

upstream myUpstream {
       ip_hash;
       server server1.com weight=1;
       server server2.com weight=1;
}


server {
    #---- Server Domain neme
    server_name www.server.com;

    keepalive_requests 100;
    keepalive_timeout 20s;


    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ;

    # ssl config
    ssl_certificate path.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privateKeyPath.pem;

    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:SALT;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        limit_req zone=mylimit burst=10 nodelay;

        proxy_pass https://myUpstream;
        proxy_set_header  X-Scheme $scheme;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = server.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    listen         80;
    server_name server.com;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    if ($host = www.server.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    listen         80;
    server_name www.server.com;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ;
    ssl_certificate path.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privatekeyPath.pem;

   server_name server.com;
   return         301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;

}
```

Comment: with the current config there is no cache in nginx configured, do you wsnt to use it like this?

Comment: Show full config

Comment: I've edited my question with full nginx config file @AlexeyTen.